# Zend framework foreach loop stop ate the first iteration

Tags: php, zend-framework, foreach, tree

I'm actually working on ZF. I have a category table with which, I want to create a tree in order to get display the data as below :

```
Category
--Sub cat 1
--Sub cat 2
----Su sub cat 1
Another Category
--Sub cat 1
//...etc...
```

I'm using the `fetchAll` method to get all my data. Everyting works fine. But then I'm now trying to create my tree into a double foreach loop as below :

```
$tree = array();
foreach($data as $parent){
    $tree[$parent->name] = array();
    foreach($data as $child){
        if($child->parent_id == $parent->id){
            $tree[$parent->name][] = $child->name;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the loop stop after the `main` loop first iteration so I'm just getting the first parent and it's sub category but it does not continue to the second parent.

My database table as the following fields :

```
id, name, parent_id
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**
Thanks to you Thibault, it did work using the good old `for` loop :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    $tree[$data[$i]->name] = array();
    for($j=0;$j<count($data);$j++){
        if($data[$j]->parent_id == $data[$i]->id){
            $tree[$data[$i]->name][] = $data[$j]->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you get more than 1 category?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yeah I have several categories return by the data base. I've check already so I don't understand why it breaks like that. Also, if I remove the second loop, everything's fine and the loop works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a conflict between the cursor of both `$data` variables.

You should use a copy of `$data` for the second `foreach` loop.

Or use `for` loops with `$i` and `$j` index, and call them via `$data[$i]` and `$data[$j]` to access the array, so the loops don't get messed up.

**EDIT**
Happy i could help, but after some research, i created this piece of code :

```
<?

class o {
 public $id;
 public $name;
 public $parent_id;
 function __construct($_id,$_name,$_parent) {
  $this->id = $_id;
  $this->name = $_name;
  $this->parent_id = $_parent;
 }
}
$data = array(
 new o(1,'toto',0),
 new o(2,'truc',1),
 new o(3,'machin',1),
 new o(4,'bidule',2),
 new o(5,'titi',3),
 new o(6,'tutu',3),
);


$tree = array();
foreach($data as $parent){
    $tree[$parent->name] = array();
    foreach($data as $child){
        if($child->parent_id == $parent->id){
            $tree[$parent->name][] = $child->name;
        }
    }
}

print_r($tree);
```

And your code works just fine :
(something must be wrong somewhere else ...)

```
Array
(
    [toto] => Array
        (
            [0] => truc
            [1] => machin
        )

    [truc] => Array
        (
            [0] => bidule
        )

    [machin] => Array
        (
            [0] => titi
            [1] => tutu
        )

    [bidule] => Array
        (
        )

    [titi] => Array
        (
        )

    [tutu] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi, I already did a copy of data before in 2 differents variables called `$parents` and `$children` but it still won't fix the issue. Also, ZF return me the data as an object so I can't use `$data[$i]`